# I accidentally deleted /boot/grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I accidentally deleted my `/boot/grub` and now I can't boot into my GRUB, nor can I edit anything related to GRUB.

Tried `grub-install /dev/sda1` but:

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).

No path or device is specified.
Try `grub-probe --help' for more information.
```

What should I do?

`lsbci`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   200G  0 part /
└─sda2   8:2    0    50M  0 part /boot
```

Comment: install to device `/dev/sda` rather than partition /dev/sda1...  (i'm assuming you need legacy; not efi/uefi...)

Comment: same error... T_T

Comment: can you add your disk info; eg. `lsblk`

Comment: how are you installing grub? are the partitions mounted?

Comment: if mounted & still running (should have said this before)  it should be `update-grub` to explore & ready for install; then `grub-install /dev/sda` .. sorry.  if you rebooted & you're running live etc; this will unlikely work as you'll have to mount & make it current first...

Comment: If running live installer, you have to mount both /boot partition and / (root) partition. Often easier to use Boot-Repair and in advanced options run the full uninstall/reinstall of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Most desktops do not need separate /boot partition and 50MB is small for a /boot.